# Is it possible to use Username and Password as a Plain text to get Office 365 Groups and users in c# code using Microsoft Graph API?

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, user, microsoft-graph, office-365-groups

The question is very straight forward.

Is it possible to use Username and Password as a Plain text to get Office 365 Groups and users in c# code using Microsoft Graph API or any other API?

If yes, then how? I need to develop an application where I need to fetch the Office 365 Groups and Users and display it to the Non Admin Users too.

Answer (score 0):

We can use SharePoint Online CSOM(**Download** [SharePoint Online Client Components SDK](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=42038)) to achieve it. The code below for your reference.

```
string targetSiteURL = @"https://xxx.sharepoint.com/sites/lz";

//set user login name and passsword 
var username = "lz@xxx.onmicrosoft.com";
var password = "Password";

var securePassword = new SecureString();
foreach (char c in password){securePassword.AppendChar(c);}

SharePointOnlineCredentials onlineCredentials = new SharePointOnlineCredentials(username, securePassword);

ClientContext ctx = new ClientContext(targetSiteURL);
ctx.Credentials = onlineCredentials;

GroupCollection groups = ctx.Web.SiteGroups;
ctx.Load(groups,gs=>gs.Include(g=>g.Title,g=>g.Users));
ctx.ExecuteQuery();

foreach(Group group in groups)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Group Name:"+group.Title);             
    foreach(User user in group.Users)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("   UserName:"+user.Title);
    }
    Console.WriteLine("-------------------------------------------");
}
Console.ReadLine();
```

Comment: I guess you interpreted the question wrong. I have specified that I need to access Office 365 Groups, Not SharePoint Groups. I tagged the SharePoint Online because I want to display the Office 365 groups in SharePoint WebPart..